# Change the appearance of a button when in active state

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I need help changing a button to look like an arrow is coming out of it to show that it is the active button. The button is wrapped in a card component.

Below is a code example:

```
        <div className="float-container">
          <div className="creator-container float-child">
            <div>
              <Card className="bg-mainBlue rounded-xl">
                <CardContent>
                  <Button
                    className=" text-white font-nunito text mx-2 pr-35 "
                    onClick={() => onFieldAdd('textField')}
                  >
                    <TextFieldsIcon />
                    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Box</p>
                  </Button>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
```

I am struggling changing the buttons appearance. My code is build in React using TypeScript. and I would like to mostly achieve this using css.

I have included a picture of my desired outcome.

[image]

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: Add `::before` to the active element and position it to the right place.

Comment: Can you mabye give me a code example. I am really stuck on this.

Comment: So you can make the `::before` element to be `display:block`, then add it the `backround:_mainBlue_` and `transform:rotate(45deg)`. Then just play with the position or margin.

Comment: The `::before` has to be pseudo-element of the Card element.

Comment: How would I make the arrow?

Comment: If the `::before` is `display:block` and do have some `width` and `height`, it creates a square. When you `transform:rotate` it and place it to the edge of the Card element, there will be only one corn of the `::before` and will be just like in your image in the description.

Comment: I am so confused...On what do I put the ::before on??

Comment: I did the code for you. Focus on the css style for the ::before.
[https://codepen.io/daniel-bedn-/pen/zYWbeeP](https://codepen.io/daniel-bedn-/pen/zYWbeeP)

Comment: Thank you so much! My last question..The arrow needs to move when each button is clicked, to show that it's the active button. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Then you need to add the `.active` class to the element (Button) you just clicked and make this `::before`  for the class `.active` and **not for the whole parent <div> Card element**. So the css would be `Button.active::before{...}`

Comment: I have improved the codepen, you can check.

Comment: You have been such an amazing help. I cannot get the code to work though. My buttons are not in an ul/li/a they are <Button> components from mui..I don't know if thats maybe the issue?? And my code is using TypeScript not JS..

Comment: I have added an image of the error/ issue I am getting. The activeButton is unhappy because it says it has already been declared?

Comment: Yes, remove the declaration of the activeButton. const activeButton = .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247466/discussion-between-daniel-bednar-and-jennifer-de-goede).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can make the `::before` element. Set it to be `display:block`, then add it the `backround:_mainBlue_` and `transform:rotate(45deg)`. Dont forget to `content:''`. Then just play with the position.

Example:
https://codepen.io/daniel-bedn-/pen/zYWbeeP